# appending nan rows according to difference of two row value

Tags: python, pandas, python-itertools

Hello i have a dataframe like:

```
df1
     A   B
0  0.7   7
1  1.0  10
2  1.2  12
3  1.4  14
4  1.8  18
5  14   7
6  17   10
```

I am trying to append nan rows according to difference between column B rows. I mean, for example, column B row 0 and row 1, has difference value 3. So i need to append 2 nan rows to have continuous integer values between them. And then I am going to do interpolation between them. Because i have large scale data and i need to do it fast, i thought it is better to do it with pandas, so please tell me pandas solution. Should i iterate them? what do you think? Final dataframe will look like this:

```
       0    1
0   0.07    7
1   0.08    8
2   0.09    9
3   0.10    10
4   0.11    11
5   0.12    12
6   0.13    13
7   0.14    14
8   0.15    15
9   0.16    16
10  0.17    17
11  0.18    18
12  14.00   7
13  16.00   8
14  18.00   9
15  17.00   10
```

That's why i am trying to get this:

```
    0          1
0   0.07     7.0
1   NaN      NaN
2   NaN      NaN
3   0.10    10.0
4   0.11    11.0
5   0.12    12.0
6   NaN      NaN
7   0.14    14.0
8   0.15    15.0
9   NaN      NaN
10  NaN      NaN
11  0.18    18.0
12  14.00    7.0
13  NaN      NaN
14  NaN      NaN
15  17.00   10.0
```

I am searching the most pythonic way, the best way for data science? Thanks.

Comment: The indexes from 12 forward don't make sense to me. Is that right?

Comment: Sorry i am going to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -

```
diff = (df['B'].shift(-1) - df['B']).fillna(1)
tmp = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(diff.mask(diff < 0, 1)))
tmp.mask(tmp.diff().eq(0)).reset_index(drop=True).interpolate()
```

**Output**

```
    A   B
0   0.7 7.0
1   0.8 8.0
2   0.9 9.0
3   1.0 10.0
4   1.1 11.0
5   1.2 12.0
6   1.3 13.0
7   1.4 14.0
8   1.5 15.0
9   1.6 16.0
10  1.7 17.0
11  1.8 18.0
12  14.0    7.0
13  15.0    8.0
14  16.0    9.0
15  17.0    10.0
```